# How to make a jsp page keyboard accessible and how to change the position of a popped up jsp page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

In the snap you can see that after clicking the Add application link, this dialog box in the left hand side is appearing. This dialog box is a .jsp page. I don't have the access to the css files that this jsp is calling.

Now my question is :

1. I want to pull it down for some pixels, without using the css. Is it possible? if yes then how ? As you can see that due to its appearance in that position the back ground links are not visible.
2. The links and the form field(search for a text) are not key board accessible. How to make them keyboard accessible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u don't have access to .css, then in your present jsp, put style to that modal window if it is having a div. as,

```
In <div ... style="margin-top: 100px;">
```

aligning the layers definitely need some style, else browser cannot identify it

Comment: Thanks ! that's working fine . Any idea to make that dialog box keyboard accessible. Its a simple jsp page but don't know why the links and the form field is not accessible by keyboard.

Comment: I see a textbox in your modal window, so once u click on a link to open modal window in the same js function write that element.focus();

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pull it down for some pixels, without using the css. Is it possible?

It /might/ be (the specifics would depend on how it was implemented), but CSS is very much the right tool for this job.

> The links and the form field(search for a text) are not key board accessible. How to make them keyboard accessible?

That depends on why they aren't keyboard accessible.